# javah -jni <classname> not working?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, javah

I've been trying to create a .h file with the command :

```
javah -jni MyClass
```

of course after doing

```
javac MyClass.java
```

which doesn't give me any error messages...

However whenever I execute the `javah -jni` command I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: can't find class file
MyClass.class in 
java.net.URLClassLoader{urls=[file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar], 
parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:./], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}}
               at gnu.classpath.tools.javah.Main.getClass(libgcj-tools.so.14)
               at gnu.classpath.tools.javah.Main.parseClasses(libgcj-tools.so.14)
               at gnu.classpath.tools.javah.Main.run(libgcj-tools.so.14)
               at gnu.classpath.tools.javah.Main.main(libgcj-tools.so.14)
```

By the way I'm working on a Windows 10 PC

Comment: 1. What `javah` command line are you using? 2. Is your class in a package? 3. Why are you using GNU CLASSPATH? It's as dead as a doornail. Let it rest in peace. Use a JDK.

Comment: 1. I just type `javah -jni MyClass directly after compiling MyClass.java  2. My class in not in a package  3. I wasn't even aware that I was using GNU CLASSPATH, please enlighten me

Comment: Take a look at the class names in the stack trace. GNU CLASSPATH was a failed and indeed doomed attempt on the part of FSF to provide an open-source Java. They never even finished 1.2 but it is still around in Linux distributions for some reason, twenty years later. Remove it and install a JDK. Why is the class name in the stack trace different from the one in the command line? Have you compiled it?

Comment: About the different class name in the stack trace, I just copied the wrong error. I have indeed compiled it... Do you mind explaining how to remove the GNU CLASSPATH? Please forgive me I am a complete beginner at this

Comment: I have no idea. Something to do with RPM I would guess, but don't quote me. Is the .class file in the current directory when you run `javah`?

Comment: @EJP Yes, the .class file is in the current file

Comment: Spelling the file name correctly? Including case? Filename agrees with internal class name?

Comment: @EJP Yes, yes, and yes!

Comment: Well try it with a JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at package defined inside MyClass. It might be that you are using some package name and then you are passing just class name - this will not work.

Make sure that class is available via CLASSPATH.

Alternatively, you can pass class location (together with package) via -cp argument for javah.

Take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

You can find there fully working, supper simple sample.

It should work out of the box. Just do:

```
git clone https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook.git
cd jnicookbook/recipes/recipeNo001
make; make test
```

If you still have issues here. It might be there is something not quite ok with your installation.

If it works for you, just make sure to use similar compilation flags as you can find inside Makefile

Have fun with JNI :)

***Update:***

As already pointed out in comments above, maybe you can switch to Oracle's JDK?

If you use Oracle's JDK there are no issues of that sort. You can easily generate C header using javah

In case you have to stick to GCJ (e.g. legacy code), maybe give it a try with

```
javah -jni -cp . Main
```

Comment: OP has already stated specifically in comments that he is not using a package name.

Comment: Ah ... yeap, now I can see that in the comment ;)